# Image scroller problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

hello every buddy
i want to make horizontal image scroller at bottom view and in the back of side big Image View. i don't know how to make image horizontal scroll.

Comment: do you want to make a horizontal slideshow? m i right?

Comment: yes i want horizontal slideshow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the image view inside a scroll view whose horizontal content size is greater than its frame width, i.e.

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 100);
[scrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

Comment: i have 4 to 5 images to show in scroll bar and this numbers are not fix it may very from 3 to 8.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `contentSize` property of the `UIScrollView` to set its content size according to your requirement and then set the property `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator` to `YES` and `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` to `NO` . But you don't require to set these two if you set frame and content size properly. Like if `_myScrollView.frame.height` and `_myScrollView.contentSize.height` is same then you don't need to set  horizontal and vertical scroll. Its vertical scroll will automatically be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scroll view with page control for a horizontal slideshow. follow the tutorial it might help you

http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/pagecontrol-example-in-iphone/